# Java - Error ListArray dinámico + pool de conexiones + Tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, mysqlconnector.jar

Tengo un error en cargar un ListArray con datos dinamicos y con pool de conexiones con Tomcat 7, mi codigo es el siguiente:

1. Servlet por defecto:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, SQLException {


   CageLoaderServlet cLoader = new CageLoaderServlet();
               cLoader.load();
       }
   ```
2. Servlet que cuenta con el array:

   ```
   public void load() throws ServletException, SQLException 

   {
       try {
           List<MiscSettings> list = MiscSettingsDAO.listarMiscSettings();
           //System.out.println(list);
           Iterator<MiscSettings> iter = list.iterator();
           while (iter.hasNext())
           System.out.println(((MiscSettings) iter).getId() +";"+ ((MiscSettings) iter).getDataname()+"; "+((MiscSettings) iter).getDatavalue()+"; "+((MiscSettings) iter).getDescription());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
       }

   }
   ```
3. Mi clase DAO  que llama al pool de coneciones:

   ```
   Connection co = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   List<MiscSettings> listaMiscSettings = new ArrayList<MiscSettings>();
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM miscsettings";
   co = DBManager.getConnection();
   ps = co.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = ps.executeQuery();

   while (rs.next()) {
       int id = rs.getInt("id");
       String dataname = rs.getString("dataname");
       String datavalue = rs.getString("datavalue");
       String description = rs.getString("description");
       MiscSettings miscsettings = new MiscSettings(id, dataname, datavalue, description);
       listaMiscSettings.add(miscsettings);
   }
   co.close();
   return listaMiscSettings;
   ```
4. Pool Connection.

   ```
   public static Connection getConnection()
   {
       Context initContext = null;
        Context envContext = null;
        DataSource ds = null;

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

         initContext = new InitialContext();
         envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/");
         ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/loadcageconfig");
         conn = ds.getConnection();

        } catch( Exception e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       DBManager.getConnection();
   }
   ```
5. Error en consola:

   ```
    javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
       at com.cage.loader.sw.utils.DBManager.getConnection(DBManager.java:23)
       at com.cage.loader.sw.dao.MiscSettingsDAO.listarMiscSettings(MiscSettingsDAO.java:56)
       at com.cage.loader.sw.servlets.CageLoaderServlet.load(CageLoaderServlet.java:35)
       at CageLoader.main(CageLoader.java:13)
   ```

por favor su apoyo con el error de ListArray con Pool e conexiones.

Comment: Te sugiero primero revisar que la conexion a la base de datos funcione. Luego revisar que el resultset traiga los valores de una consulta simple y finalmente llenar las clases con los datos extraidos. Pero prueba primero la conexion porque es posible que el error este en el acoplamiento de las distintas tecnologias que usas.

Comment: @AndyC muchas gracias por tu sugerencia.